# Table overlapping text

Tags: tables

I have a two column document and a table that I want it to be page wide.
The problem is the table overlaps with the text after the table.

Here is the table:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[b]{ | p{1cm} | p{3cm} | p{8cm} | X | }
\hline
    \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D}\\ \hline\hline
      blah & blah &blah &blah \\
      blah & blah &blah &blah \\
      blah & blah &blah &blah \\
      blah & blah &blah &blah 
 \end{tabularx}

Some TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome Text
```

The problem is that the table is printed on top of the "Some Text" paragraph.

what can I do ?

Comment: Your code is missing some line change commands ` \\ `. Can you please provide a complete document illustrating the problem?

Comment: Please always post complete documents not just fragments, but you want to nest this in a `table*` environment to make a page-wide float. Also you need \\ as Gonzalo said.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To make a page wide float in a two-column document you need the `table*` form:

```
\begin{table*}
\begin{tabularx}.....
\end{tabularx}
\caption{my one-column table}
\end{table*}

main two-column text ...
```